# Convert SQL Query to MySQL with Split Time Interval

Tags: mysql, time, intervals

I wanted to request help in achieving the following scenario, we have table that logs user activity and with in the single row; we log start and stop time and calculate the duration using a mysql trigger when end time is updated in the row.

Following is the table structure

```
---------------------------------------------------
USERs Activity Table
---------------------------------------------------

created_at              Event       User            Start_timestamp         End_Timestamp           Duration
-------------------     ---------   -------         -------------------     -------------------     --------
2018-11-20 18:01:22     LOGIN       john.doe        2018-11-20 18:01:22     2018-11-20 19:01:22     3600
2018-11-20 18:01:22     LOGIN       jane.miller     2018-11-20 18:10:03     2018-11-20 20:10:03     7200
2018-11-20 18:15:16     BREAK       john.doe        2018-11-20 18:15:16     2018-11-20 18:33:47     300
2018-11-20 18:33:47     ONCALL      john.doe        2018-11-20 18:33:47     2018-11-20 18:36:47     180
```

We want to generate a report which can give us 15 minutes interval of all users as shown below

```
---------------------------------------------------
Desired Result in 15 minutes time interval 
---------------------------------------------------

Intervals               User            LOGIN TIME      BREAK TIME      CALL TIME
-------------------     ----------      ----------      ----------      ---------
2018-11-20 18:00:00     john.doe        00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 18:00:00     jane.miller     00:04:57        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 18:15:00     john.doe        00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 18:15:00     jane.miller     00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 18:30:00     john.doe        00:15:00        00:15:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 18:30:00     jane.miller     00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 18:45:00     john.doe        00:15:00        00:03:15        00:03:00
2018-11-20 18:45:00     jane.miller     00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 19:00:00     john.doe        00:01:22        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 19:00:00     jane.miller     00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 19:15:00     jane.miller     00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 19:30:00     jane.miller     00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 19:45:00     jane.miller     00:15:00        00:00:00        00:00:00
2018-11-20 20:00:00     jane.miller     00:10:03        00:00:00        00:00:00
-------------------                     ----------      ----------      ----------
```

What I am unable to achieve is that we have a single row for each event and if I get report based on 15 minutes interval, I get the total duration against the interval the event started in and it doesn't look right to show 30 mins of time in a 15 min interval. It should however be shown e.g. 3 mins in 1 interval and 12 mins in other; the actual time spent in each interval.

Please advise on how this can be achieved. I also created a temp table which is populated with 15 min intervals that I want the data to be generated against and use joins but I am not an expert in SQL and need help / advise from you guys.

Following is the query I have been playing around with but no success so far.

```
    SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(a.created_at) - TIME_TO_SEC(a.created_at) % (15 * 60)),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") AS time_interval
      , a.user
      , SEC_TO_TIME(IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.event = 'LOGIN' THEN a.duration END),0)) AS login_time
      , SEC_TO_TIME(IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.event = 'BREAK' THEN a.duration END),0)) AS break_time
      , SEC_TO_TIME(IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.event = 'ONCALL' THEN a.duration END),0)) AS talk_time
    FROM users_activity AS a
    WHERE a.created_at > '2018-11-20 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY time_interval, a.user
    ORDER BY time_interval DESC;
```

SQL Fiddle with Schema https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d64482c499a07e9d1c7ec232915969e

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you put an sql fiddle ( or equivalent ) together for us we might find it a little easier to help you.  Rebuilding the relevant schema from the question data is not something I'm particularly interested in undertaking.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about the fiddle. 
here it is

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ada4b/1/0